# iBatis LazyLoading Configuration

Tags: lazy-loading, ibatis

I need to serialize some objects loaded by iBatis, but am getting NotSerializableException because lazyLoadingEnabled="true".

I see that this is a known limitation (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IBATIS-529), but I'm yet to find a workaround outside of turning lazy loading off for the entire application.

The question I have is whether there is any finer grained control over lazy loading.  This is currently enabled/disabled in the sqlMapConfig/settings which applies to all the sqlMap resources.  Is there a way to enable/disable this programmatically or just for certain sqlMaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never found a solution for controlling lazy loading explicitly...however, I did solve my issue by simply converting my object into XML (therefore loading all necessary fields explicitly) and using that for my payload (to avoid object serialization altogether)...obviously not ideal, but it worked for my needs and seems on par performance wise (given that object serialization is slow anyways)

Answer (score 0):

Find a configuration file in your project with `<sqlMapConfig>` element and in the nested `<settings>` element, you can specify `lazyLoadingEnabled="false"` but if your query fetches other complex objects with external fetch, you surely will have a real **Stack Overflow** problem!